# Regex check if number to n-root is not floating point

Tags: regex

I am trying to work out how to do something using regular expressions.

Basically, I want to check if a number is equal to a base number (i.e. 2) to the power of n.

For example, I need something thats checks if number i == 2, 4, 8, 16 or 32 then do something.

Edit:
The problem lies where the number is actually coming from a varchar column in a legacy database. I could parse it out then do something like kobi reccommended but there is another problem where the number is in a delimited list i.e. (1,2,3,32). Therefore, I thought it would be easier to use regex as it would save a number of steps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So don't use a regex - it's definitely wrong for you. You can simply check by taking the logarithm of the number, and see if you get a whole number - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%282%2C+8%29

Comment: I was writing a response but decided it would be better to add it as additional information to original post. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: I'm still not very clear on the problem - you have a string like `1,2,3,32` - what should be done with it? It has 4 numbers: do you need to extract `1`, `2` and `32`? or invalidate it because it has `3`? and what about different bases?

Comment: sorry, i have revised the problem and i actually need to validate that number at index x (say 3 for 32) when 2 raised to power n, n is a whole number. so, it would be true in this case as 2^5 = 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python:

```
import re
a = str(bin(number))
if re.match(r"[^1]*1[^1]*$", a):
    print "power of two"
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `^10*$`? Also, I think 2 was just an example, and the OP may need different bases, and I'm sure (ok, hope) Python has better ways of dealing with this problem...

Comment: the regex will need to scale to find any number that has a squared root value which equals a whole number. for example, in it's present state, it needs to check if the number is 2, 4, 8, ..., 512.

Comment: @user - in the question you asked for "2 to the power of n" - e.g. 2^2, 2^3, 2^4... Now you're talking about "has a squared root value which equals a whole number", e.g. 1^2, 2^2, 3^2... - hardly the same thing!

Comment: hi sorry, i know i wasn't completely sure on the requirements. if i had the reputation then I would vote up your anwser for answering the original (badly formed) question